# What algorithm does SKlearn use for minimzing the MSE?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am using Scikit-learn library to do a linear regression. Everything is simple and straightforward.
With 6 lines of code, I can do the job. However, I want to know exactly what is happening behind.

Since I am a beginner in ML, maybe my question is wrong, but I am wondering what algorithm does Scikit-learn is using to minimize the mean squared error in its linear_regression method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html):

> From the implementation point of view, this is just plain Ordinary Least Squares (scipy.linalg.lstsq) wrapped as a predictor object.

You can give a look at the source code too [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/bac89c2/sklearn/linear_model/base.py#L485), where it calls [linalg.lstsq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html).

---

An extra note about *what's happening behind*:

If the linear formula is `a * x + b`, you can access the coefficients (`a`) and the bias (`b`) with the attributes `coef_` and `intercept_` of the trained model.

A toy example generating the identity diagonal from 3 dots to show the `coef_` and `intercept_` attributes:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

X = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3])

lg = LinearRegression()
lg.fit(X, y)
lg.coef_ # 1
lg.intercept_ # ~ 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Scikit-Learn's [LinearRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) uses the closed form solution, i.e the OLS solution. It specifically uses the [Ordinary Least Squares](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) solver from scipy.